# How to get list of the ec2 instance on the member account

Tags: aws-organizations

I have created an aws account via AWS Organization through aws cli.
How can I get the list of ec2 instances on the created member aws account?
How can I access it without recovering root password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I was able to to get ec2 instance list automatically, without any manual actions.
Once Member account has been created AWS automatically creates *OrganizationAccountAccessRole* role. Switching to that role it is possible to get admin access on member account.
This is the code to switch to that role

```
sts_client = self.aws_service.create_aws_sts()

assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/OrganizationAccountAccessRole",
        RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
    )
credentials = assumed_role_object['Credentials']

s3_resource=boto3.resource(
'ec2',
aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'])

for instance in s3_resource.instances.all():
    print(instance.Id)
```

Hope it will help who had similar question,

Answer (score 1):

Since the member AWS account has been created recently, there would not be any EC2 instances (or any other resources) created in it.

In order to access the account without recovering password, you can use the "Switch Role" feature as described here - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/organizations-member-account-access/

Once you're able to login, you could create your access keys and run CLI commands.

Comment: Is there a way to access it via the cli command, not manually?

Comment: AFAIK - No, not unless you can create access keys for an IAM user in the new account.